# Angular - "TypeError: Cannot freeze" when dispatching an action

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm working on an angular app that uses ngrx store & effects. I get

> "TypeError: Cannot freeze"

error when dispatching an action from my component. I wrote it for a file upload feature. I think that I'm mutating the state but cannot figure out where and how to solve it.
Here's my detailed code:

`Actions:`

```
export enum FileUploadActionTypes {
    UploadFile = '[File Upload] Upload File',
    UploadFileSuccess = '[File Upload] Upload File Success',
    UploadFileFailure = '[File Upload] Upload File Failure'
}

export class UploadFile implements Action {
    readonly type = FileUploadActionTypes.UploadFile;

    constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export class UploadFileSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = FileUploadActionTypes.UploadFileSuccess;

    constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export class UploadFileFailure implements Action {
    readonly type = FileUploadActionTypes.UploadFileFailure;

    constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export type FileUploadActionsUnion = UploadFile | UploadFileSuccess | UploadFileFailure;
```

`Service:`

```
export class FileUploadService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

    }
    uploadFile(file: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.post<any[]>('/api-url/', file);
    }
}
```

`Effect:`

```
@Effect()
uploadFile$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<UploadFile>(FileUploadActionTypes.UploadFile),
    mergeMap(action => this.fileUploadService.uploadFile(action.payload).pipe(
        map(result => new UploadFileSuccess(result)),
        catchError(error => of(new UploadFileFailure(error)))
    ))
)
```

`Reducer:`

```
export interface State {
    fileUploadSuccessResponse: any,
    fileUploadFailureResponse: any
}

export const initialState = {
    fileUploadSuccessResponse: null,
    fileUploadFailureResponse: null
}

export const getFileUploadSuccessResponse = state => state.fileUploadSuccessResponse;
export const getFileUploadFailureResponse = state => state.fileUploadFailureResponse;

export function reducer(state: State = initialState, action: FileUploadActionsUnion):State {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FileUploadActionTypes.UploadFile: {
            return {
                ...state
            }
        }
        case FileUploadActionTypes.UploadFileSuccess: {
            return {
                ...state,
                fileUploadSuccessResponse: action.payload
            }
        }
        case FileUploadActionTypes.UploadFileFailure: {
            return {
                ...state,
                fileUploadFailureResponse: action.payload
            }
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the payload look like?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It appears you are using the `ngrx-store-freeze` npm package. This package ensures that any updates you make to the store are not mutated directly. Part of this process is to apply an `Object.freeze()` to the `payload` object of the action you are attempting to dispatch. i.e. `this.store.dispatch(new UploadFiles(file))`.

Default behavior for the `<input type="file">` control is to save it's value as a `FileList` object. Because this object is a primitive data type, Javascript will treat it as read-only, thus preventing you from writing to it's properties. This also explains why `Object.freeze()` fails, as it cannot apply a freeze to a read only data type.

I experienced the same issue recently using NGRX and the `<input type="file">` form control. The fix was to clone the `FileList` into a new object before dispatching to the store.

```
onChange(control: FormControl) {
  const primitiveFileList: FileList = control.value;
  const clonedFiles = { ...primitiveFileList };
  this.store.dispatch(new UploadFiles(clonedFiles));
}
```

If anyone else knows any potential downfalls to this approach, I'd appreciate your input.

Comment: In my case just cloning the FileList object dropped the `length` property and the `item()` function. So I need to add the length property to the clone myself, and also use the `[i]` instead of `item(i)` later.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

*Before dispatching you need to make the payload non-writable.*

**A)** Make a deep copy of the payload. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload))`.

```
this.store.dispatch(
  MyActions.actionName({
    payload: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload))
  })
);
```

Or

**B)**  Use `Object.freeze(payload)` method.

```
this.store.dispatch(
  MyActions.actionName({
    payload: Object.freeze(payload)
  })
);
```